# Docker Compose Fails to Create MongoDB User for Node.js Container Connection

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, docker, nosql

I am working on setting up a Dockerized environment with MongoDB and a Node.js application. My goal is to create a MongoDB user with a password through docker-compose.yml, which the Node.js app can use to connect to the MongoDB container. However, I'm encountering issues where the user and password do not seem to be created, preventing my Node.js application from establishing a connection to MongoDB.

Here's how I have set up my docker-compose.yml, Dockerfile, and the MongoDB initialization script:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: myuser
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypassword
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: mydb
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

  nodejs:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
```

Dockerfile (for Node.js app):

```
FROM node:21

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

Node.js Connection (app.js):

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = "mongodb://myuser:mypassword@mongodb:27017/mydb";

function connectWithRetry() {
  MongoClient.connect(url, {}, function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Failed to connect to mongo on startup - retrying in 5 sec', err);
      setTimeout(connectWithRetry, 5000);
    } else {
      
      var dbo = db.db("mydb");
      var myobj = { name: "John Doe", address: "Highway 37" };
      
      dbo.collection("users").insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("1 document inserted");
        
        dbo.collection("users").findOne({}, function(err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log(result.name);
          db.close();
        });
      });



    }
  });
}

connectWithRetry();
```

When I run docker-compose up, the MongoDB container starts, but the Node.js application fails to connect to the database with a MongoNetworkError. It seems like the user and password are not being created in MongoDB as expected.

Has anyone faced a similar issue or can point out what I might be doing wrong? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

From the code if I try wihtout using user and password it is getting connected but I don't want to setup that user and password seperately as I am ready those information from different ENV_NAME.env file I want this node.js app should connect and do it's job. If is not possible this way then let me know about other process.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the error in the logs of the Database :

```json
{
   ...
   "msg":"Failed to authenticate",
   "attr":{
      "user":"myuser",
      "db":"mydb",
      "error":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"myuser\" for db \"mydb\"",
   }
   ...
}
```

According to [the documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo), section *MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME* *MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD*  :

> This user is **created in the admin authentication database** and given the role of root, which is a "superuser" role.

Therefore, is you want to connect to the `mydb` database, you would need to create a Mongo script under the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` folder inside the Mongo container to create a user for that database (use volumes for this) : The script would look something like this :

```js
db.createUser(
  {
    user: 'mydbuser',
    pwd: 'mydbpassword',
    roles: [{ role: 'readWrite', db: 'mydb' }],
  },
);
```

Then, edit the connection script in your code to :

```js
const url = "mongodb://mydbuser:mydbpassword@mongodb:27017/mydb";
```

Comment: Yes, I copied docker-compose.yml from the wrong location. I updated that piece of code, but this issue persists. I noticed if I keep the connection string like

mongodb://myuser:mypassword@mongodb:27017/mydb

then everything works correctly, but I can not use the user and password provided in the docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: I just edited my answer as well :)